# grammar of 'had we but world enough and time...'

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction

'Had we but world enogh and time...' is a phrase from a famous poem. Can you explain the grammar of this poetic phrase?

Answer (score 1):

The phase is from Marvel's "To His Coy Mistress", written some time around 1650-1660. It therefore uses both slightly archaic grammar along with poetic brevity which make it difficult for a more novice modern English speaker.

> 'Had we but'

The first three words are probably most difficult to grasp, as it uses forms and vocabulary that are not often used any more in standard English.

'had we' is an inversion of verb and subject to create a conditional clause. Combined with 'but', which is not being used as a conjunction, but as an adverb to mean 'only/just', and you end up with the following meaning:

> "If we only had ...".

By 'world enough, and time', Marvel means 'if our ability to travel anywhere, and to take any amount of time, was unlimited'.

So in total, you have:

> "If we only had an unlimited supply of space and time ...".

The poem's theme, in essence, is a man telling his 'mistress' (ie the female object of his affections, who was not a mistress (ie a secret lover) in the modern sense) to 'get a move on'. In today's terms, he is trying to get his girlfriend to 'put out' and he is frustrated by her refusal to cooperate.

Which only goes to show you can get away with all sorts of noxious behaviour, so long as you put it in iambic tetrameter.